# How to speed up plotting with PlotPoints?

Tags: plotting, astronomy, timing

I'm plotting an ellipse `1/(1 - e Cos[x])` with `e=0.9` using `PolarPlot`. Taking $x\in[0,2\pi)$, i.e. one revolution, everything looks fine. But taking `n=500` revolutions produces something very vaguely resembling an ellipse:

```
e = 0.9;
n = 500;
PolarPlot[1/(1 - e Cos[x]), {x, 0, 2 n π}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 700, FrameTicks -> False]
```

[image]

The solution is quite straightforward, and uses `PlotPoints`:

```
PolarPlot[1/(1 - e Cos[x]), {x, 0, 2 n π}, Frame -> True, 
Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 700, FrameTicks -> False, 
PlotPoints -> 10^5]
```

[image]

Without `PlotPoints` generating the image took 0.05 sec, with `PlotPoints -> 10^5` it needed almost 4 sec - rather understandable as it has more to plot.

Finally, consider a different approach: generate 500 images for each revolution separately, without `PlotPoints`, and `Show` them together:

```
Show@Table[PolarPlot[1/(1 - e Cos[x]), {x, 2 (i - 1) π, 2 i π}, 
Frame -> True, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 700, 
FrameTicks -> False], {i, 1, 500}]
```

[image]

That looks neat, but takes an enourmous 9 sec.

The thing is that I'm going to plot something like this hundreds of times, so `PlotPoints` will need a few minutes to generate a set of images like this. **My question is:** can this be sped up while keeping the plot looking nice? The third approach, with `Show`, is meant to be a demonstration that in fact just `PolarPlot` works fine for each revolutions, but fails in a longer run. Of course plotting this takes such a long time because it creates, stores and stacks 1000 images.

**NOTES:** Taking `10^4` instead of `10^5` won't do because (i) it only improves by a factor of two, (ii) in fact I'm going to have a slightly *wiggly* ellipse (perturbations in celestial mechanics) so that won't give enough detail. This is also the reason why I don't think that sampling the ellipse and using a `ListPlot` will work as (i) if the sampling will be too sparse, the details will be lost, and (ii) using a large enough number of points will take time to generate, store and plot them.

**EDIT:** Using `MaxRecursion`:

[image]

and the timings for generation of each case:

[image]

It looks like `MaxRecursion=11` or `12` is sufficient, and speeds up the thing by a factor of between 4 and 8 - quite neat.

Still, is there a way to speed it up even more? It's not particularly crucial, but now I'm just curious how fast this can be done.

Comment: It's generally discouraged to edit your question with posted answers. If you want to encourage more answers that's fine of course. http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1918/should-we-discourage-editing-questions-to-include-a-copy-of-the-accepted-answer That said, you did add a lot yourself, so I don't know.

Comment: @Feyre Your link is about incorporating someone's answer into the question. I made an edit because before it was just incorrect. I don't see any reason why a mathematically incorrect statement couldn't be corrected. I wouldn't mind if you edited your answer too. That would make this thread clear for any potential future reader.

Comment: I meant the thing about `MaxRecursion`. I at least wouldn't do it if you do get a more definitive answer.

Comment: @Feyre Ah, sorry, I misunderstood you. Yeah, I indeed took the idea from your answer to estimate how can this improve my issue, and at this point I agree with you comment. But I explicitly write "Still, is there a way to speed it up even more?" so indeed I hope that someone maight present another idea here. I apologize if something was unclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that with `n=1000` you have `500` revolutions.
`MaxRecursion` is the go to here, I tend to use `PlotPoints` only when there are tiny features like narrow peaks which are missing.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 PolarPlot[1/(1 - e Cos[x]), {x, 0, n π}, Frame -> True, 
   Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 700, FrameTicks -> False, 
   MaxRecursion -> 12];]
AbsoluteTiming[
 PolarPlot[1/(1 - e Cos[x]), {x, 0, n π}, Frame -> True, 
   Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 700, FrameTicks -> False, 
   PlotPoints -> 10^5];]
```

> `{0.975767, Null}
>   {3.65704, Null}`

Comment: Yeah, I messed up with the `n`. I edited my post so that it's consistent now.

Answer (score 9):

It's a listable expression, so you can plot it with a high precision fixed step size very quickly:

```
e = 0.9;
n = 500;
Graphics@Line@With[{x = Range[0, 2 n Pi, 0.01]},
    Transpose[{Cos[x]/(1 - e Cos[x]), Sin[x]/(1 - e Cos[x])}]
    ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With a fixed step size the number of points required is determined by the part of the curve that requires the most careful sampling. For this curve the curvature is rather uniform and no part of the curve requires a lot more careful sampling than any other part of the curve. So for this example, the number of points required with a fixed step size will be comparable to the number of points that `PolarPlot` uses. If this is also true for the curve you are actually trying to draw, then this approach may also be preferable in that case.

Answer (score 5):

The following tables show that the major part of the time to plot is proportional to the number of function evaluations, which for the OP's function is about a 10 microseconds per evaluation, or about 100 times as slow as C.E.'s method.  Recursive subdivision adds a small overhead, which is not tremendously significant.  However, comparing the extremes,

```
MaxRecursion -> 12, PlotPoints -> 50      (* 50 is the default setting *)
MaxRecursion -> 1,  PlotPoints -> 100000
```

we see that for roughly the same number of sample points, the extra recursion adds almost 30% to the execution time over the high number for `PlotPoints`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The "error" was from an estimate of the maximum distance between the line segments of the plot and the actual ellipse.  An error of 0.1% represents one pixel in an image of width 1000, which should give a pretty good plot.  (It was also chosen because of the OP's remark that `MaxRecursion` of `11` or `12` for the default number of `PlotPoints` seemed sufficient.)

The general rule is that when you need denser sampling everywhere raise `PlotPoints`.  When denser sampling is needed in a limited part of the domain, where the bending of the curve is not being rendered accurately, then raise `MaxRecursion`.  Note that for raising `MaxRecursion` to be effective, the `PlotPoints` sampling has to be dense enough to detect the bending that needs further refinement. (Worst case example: Sampling `Sin[x]` every `2 Pi` results in a straight-line plot with no bending and no *apparent* need for further refinement.) How much bending is tolerated is controlled by
[`Method -> {Refinement -> {ControlValue -> (*radian angle*) }}`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=ControlValue)
or by [`Method -> {"MaxBend" -> 1}`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=MaxBend) (now apparently deprecated).  Note that the recursive refinement algorithm is not publicly known, as far as I know. It generally examines the angle change at each segment and subdivides if it is too great, but that is not the whole story.  Subdivision occurs, shown in the tables above, each time `MaxRecursion` is increased.  Careful inspection shows that it sometimes occurs in places where it is unneeded, well after having satisfied the bending tolerance.

**Code dump**

Note the execution times in the tables above.  Expect to take the sum of them to reproduce the table, depending on machine speed.

```
(* Collect data on a plot: {time, npts, error, plot}
   Memoized so that one can play with the results; takes < 0.5 GB *)
Clear[pdata];
pdata[pp_, mr_] := pdata[pp, mr] = 
   Module[{e = 0.9, n = 500, plot, time, pts, npts = 0, radii, angles,
      error},
    {time, plot} = 
     AbsoluteTiming@
      PolarPlot[1/(1 - e Cos[x]), {x, 0, 2*n* π}, 
       PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thin], Frame -> True, 
       Axes -> False, FrameTicks -> False, MaxRecursion -> mr, 
       PlotPoints -> pp];
    {pts} = Cases[plot, Line[p_] :> p, Infinity];
    npts = Length@pts;
    radii = Norm /@ pts;
    angles = ArcCos[(radii - 1)/(e radii)];
    error = 
     Max@Abs[1/(1 - e Cos[Mean /@ Partition[angles, 2, 1]]) - 
        Norm /@ Mean /@ Partition[pts, 2, 1]];
    {time, npts, error, plot}];
{$time, $npts, $error, $plot} = Range[4]; (* parts of pdata[] *)

mypts = Round[50*((10^4/5)^(1/5))^Range[0, 5]];
mymr = Range[0, 12]~Append~15;
Labeled[
 TableForm[
  Table[
   Style[
    pdata[pp, mr][[$time]],
    ColorData["RedGreenSplit"][
     UnitStep[0.01 - pdata[pp, mr][[$error]]]]
    ],
   {mr, mymr},
   {pp, mypts}
   ],
  TableHeadings -> {mymr, mypts}],
 {"MaxRecursion", "PlotPoints", 
  Row[{"Evaluation time, by options settings, colored by error ( ", 
    ColorData["RedGreenSplit"][0], " > 0.1%, ", 
    ColorData["RedGreenSplit"][1], " ≤ 0.1%)"}, 
   BaseStyle -> {Medium}]},
 {Left, Top, Bottom}, RotateLabel -> True,
 BaseStyle -> {"Label", 10}, LabelStyle -> "Label"
 ]

Labeled[
 TableForm[
  Table[
   Style[
    pdata[pp, mr][[$npts]],
    ColorData["RedGreenSplit"][
     UnitStep[0.01 - pdata[pp, mr][[$error]]]]
    ],
   {mr, mymr},
   {pp, mypts}
   ],
  TableHeadings -> {mymr, mypts}],
 {"MaxRecursion", "PlotPoints", 
  Row[{"Evaluations, by options settings, colored by error ( ", 
    ColorData["RedGreenSplit"][0], " > 0.1%, ", 
    ColorData["RedGreenSplit"][1], " ≤ 0.1%)"}, 
   BaseStyle -> {Medium}]},
 {Left, Top, Bottom}, RotateLabel -> True,
 BaseStyle -> {"Label", 10}, LabelStyle -> "Label"
 ]
```

Comment: So, the compact message is that taking a careful combination of `MaxRecursion` and `PlotPoints` will do the job best as possible? Btw, +1 for the great tables!

Comment: @corey979 Yes, and the best settings depend on the function being plotted.      And if, as in your ellipse, uniform, dense sampling does a good job, then C.E.'s method will be the best for speed.