# Long running animation shows poor approximation to trajectory

Tags: animation, parametric-functions

Consider the following example of a circle, that gets drawn a total amount of 100 times. As you can see if you run the animation, the circle becomes a polygonal chain after a while. Now I wonder how to fix that, so the circle actually stays a circle.

```
Animate[
  Show[
    ParametricPlot[{Sin[tf], Cos[tf]}, {tf, 0, t}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
      AspectRatio -> Automatic]], 
  {t, 0.01, 200 Pi}, 
  AnimationRunning -> True]
```

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125517/how-to-speed-up-plotting-with-plotpoints) appears to be closely related.

Answer (score 2):

In order to keep the animation going at the high rate you have requested, Mathematica is using `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"`. This makes for a rather crude approximation to the circular trajectory being plotted. Try this for a slower but higher quality animation.

```
Animate[
  ParametricPlot[{Sin[tf], Cos[tf]}, {tf, 0, t},
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
    AspectRatio -> Automatic],
  {t, .1, 100, .1},
  DisplayAllSteps -> True,
  AnimationRunning -> True]
```