# Numerical Integration of a Complicated Function

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, summation

I am evaluating the numerical integration it takes very much long time. Can somebody suggest to improve the code? Code runs smoothly for the first plot given by `h1`. But when it comes to the numerical integration and summation it takes long hours to run.

```
\[Gamma]3 = 3;
\[Gamma]2 = 0.05*\[Gamma]3;
Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], TH] = 8*\[Gamma]3;
Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], TH] = 0;
vf = 3;
\[HBar] = 1;
c = 1;
e = 1;

d21 = -(\[Gamma]2/2 + 
     I*(\[CapitalDelta]p - Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], TH]) + 
     2*\[CapitalGamma]);
d31 = -(\[Gamma]3/2 + I*\[CapitalDelta]p);

\[Omega] = 45;
B = 3;

\[Chi][x_] := (-I*d21)/(
  d21*d31 + Abs[Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], TH]]^2*Sin[\[Pi] *x]^2);

\[Omega]c = Sqrt[2]/Sqrt[(c*\[HBar])/(e*B)];
\[Omega]31 = ((Sign[2]*\[HBar]*Sqrt[2] + 
     Sign[1]*\[HBar]*1)*\[Omega]c)/\[HBar];

f = 5;

\[CapitalDelta]p = \[Omega]31/(2*\[Pi]) - \[Omega]/(2*\[Pi]);
\[CapitalLambda] = 4*\[Lambda];

L = 5;
\[Lambda] = 0.25;

t1[x_] := Exp[-(Pi/\[Lambda])*Im[\[Chi][x]]*L]*
  Exp[I*Pi/\[Lambda]*Re[\[Chi][x]]*L]

h1 = DensityPlot[Abs[t1[x]], {x, -5, 5},{\[CapitalGamma], 0, 4},
  ColorFunction->"SunsetColors", PlotRange->All, PlotPoints->80,
  LabelStyle->Directive[Black, Large],Frame->True, PlotLegends->Automatic]

m = 2;    
g1[n_, x_] := 1/\[CapitalLambda]*Abs[t1[x]]*
  Exp[-((I*2*\[Pi]*n*x)/\[CapitalLambda])]

e1[n_] := NIntegrate[g1[n, x], {x, 0, \[CapitalLambda]}, 
  Method -> "MultiPeriodic"]

e3[x1_] := Sum[e1[n]*Exp[-I*m*n^2*\[Pi]]*
  Exp[-I*(2 \[Pi]*n*x1)/\[CapitalLambda]], {n, -10, 10}]

h2 = DensityPlot[Abs[e3[x1]], {x1, -5, 5},
  {\[CapitalGamma], 0, 4}, PlotRange->All,
    ColorFunction->"SunsetColors", PlotPoints->50,
    PlotLegends->Automatic, LabelStyle->Directive[Black, Large]]
```

Comment: Is the above supposed to be Latex? it is hard to read. Do you happen to have the Mathematica code or just Latex? If just Latex, the above does not render in mathjax as you can see.

Comment: @Nasser I have edited the question and changed the format.

Comment: You do not have "\\[CapitalGamma]" defined anywhere. Numerical integration will not work otherwise. Maybe you forgot to copy it.

Comment: Plotting against the Capital gamma.see h1 and h2

Comment: Yes, I see that, but you are calling `e3[x1]` from inside the plot, while your function `e3` is calling `e1` which has no access to the value of `Capital gamma`. Look carefully at the code and you will see. You should then be passing `Capital gamma` to `e3` and it in turn passes it to `e1`.

Comment: It runs and give me the plot also. But it takes 2 hrs to run. can you suggest any changes

Comment: I see it is slow. But I am having hard time seeing how it will even run. Plot is calling `e3[x1]`, which in turn calls `e1[n]` which in turn calls `NIntegrate` on `g1[n,x]` But `g1[n,x]` calls `t1[x]` which calls `X[x]` which uses `d21` which uses "Capital gamma". So how does `d21` gets the value of "Capital gamma" to evaluate the `NIntegrate`? This is very strange that it works for you like this. anyway, code that uses lots of global variables is hard to debug. Each function should be passed everything it needs to work on. This makes debugging much easier.

Comment: @Nasser What should i do?

Comment: @Naseer thank you for your reply. using quality option gives the required result but it has distortion. When i use plot point option to smooth the result again it takes very large time.

Comment: Yes, adding more point will slow it down. It seems to have exponential effect. This is not new. It is know if you make `PlotPoints->` larger than default., things will slow down. see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125517/how-to-speed-up-plotting-with-plotpoints for example. May be you try to change `MaxRecursion` and see if this has any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it takes 2 hrs to run.

Well, you are calling sum for 20 items, each one does integration. And this is all done for each sampling point. So there is a lot to do.

If you change to `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` it finishes much faster also.

But this finishes in 70 seconds for me

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And this in finishes in 354 seconds

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Link to [notebook.nb](https://12000.org/tmp/09052023/notebook.nb)

### Code with changes made

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
γ3=3
γ2 = 0.05*γ3
ΩTH = 8*γ3
ΔTH=0
vf=3
ℏ=1
c=1
e=1
d21[Γ_]:=-(γ2/2+I*(Δp-ΔTH)+2*Γ)
d31=-(γ3/2+I*Δp)
ω=45
B=3
χ[x_?NumericQ,Γ_?NumericQ]:=(-I*d21[Γ])/(d21[Γ]*d31+Abs[ΩTH]^2*Sin[π*x]^2)
ωc=Sqrt[2]/Sqrt[(c*ℏ)/(e*B)]

ω31=((Sign[2]*ℏ*Sqrt[2]+Sign[1]*ℏ*1)*ωc)/ℏ

f=5

Δp=ω31/(2*π)-ω/(2*π)

Λ=4*λ

L=5

λ=0.25

t1[x_?NumericQ,Γ_?NumericQ]:=Exp[-(Pi/λ)*Im[χ[x,Γ]]*L]*Exp[I*Pi/λ*Re[χ[x,Γ]]*L]

h1=DensityPlot[Abs[t1[x,Γ]],{x,-5,5},{Γ,0,4},ColorFunction->"SunsetColors",PlotRange->All,PlotPoints->80,LabelStyle->Directive[Black,Large],Frame->True,PlotLegends->Automatic]

m = 2;

g1[n_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ, Γ_?NumericQ] := 
 1/Λ*Abs[t1[x, Γ]]*
  Exp[-((I*2*π*n*x)/Λ)]

e1[n_?NumericQ, Γ_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[g1[n, x, Γ], {x, 0, Λ}, 
  Method -> "MultiPeriodic"]

e3[x1_?NumericQ, Γ_?NumericQ] := 
 Sum[e1[n, Γ]*Exp[-I*m*n^2*π]*
   Exp[-I*(2 π*n*x1)/Λ], {n, -10, 10}]

Timing@DensityPlot[
  Abs[e3[x1, Γ]], {x1, -5, 5}, {Γ, 0, 4}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Large], 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```